# How can I go about getting the parent directory of a directory

Tags: java

How can I go about getting the parent directory of a directory?

```
File parent = new File("");
System.out.println("Parent directory : " + parent.getParent());
```

prints `Parent directory : null`

I have a Maven multi-module project and would like to go to the parent folder then get back into each of the module folders and sub-folders getting all the jars in them.

```
parent  
    distributor  
        src.controllers  
            Dist.java  
    module1  
        src.controllers  
            1App.java  
        target  
            module1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar-  
    module2  
        src.controllers  
            2App.java  
        target  
            module2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar-
```

Above, I wold get from Dist.java to **parent** then into **module1** and **module2**

Comment: What directory do you want to get the parent of?

Comment: You need to specify an actual file path in order to traverse upwards and get the parent directory.

Comment: If you want the parent directory of the current directory, use `new File("").getCanonicalFile().getParent()`.

Comment: I did an Update to the question expounding more on it

Comment: At runtime, you have class files (not `.java` files); it sounds like you want to add a [`src/main/resources`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html) folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting javadoc of [`File.getParent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParent%28%29) (emphasis mine):

> Returns the pathname string of this **abstract pathname**'s parent, or `null` if this pathname does not name a parent directory.
>
> The *parent* of an abstract pathname consists of the pathname's prefix, if any, and each name in the pathname's name sequence except for the last. If the name sequence is empty then the pathname does not name a parent directory.

Remember, a `File` object represent the path **string**, not an actual file on the file system. The string `""` does not have a parent. The string `"a/b/c"` has `"a/b"` as the parent, even if they don't physically exist.

So, first you have to resolve the path `""` to a real path by calling `getCanonicalFile()`. *Then* you can find the parent directory.

```
File file = new File("").getCanonicalFile();
System.out.println("Parent directory : " + file.getParent());
```